# Swift Text Label Nil Even With Default Value

Tags: swift, label, viewcontroller

This is driving me crazy. The function `updateTextView()` is being called, verified by the print statements, but it is not setting the label in my view controller, and the print statements for the label are returning nil even though it has a default value set which is visible when the app is loaded. Whats more perplexing is that I set up a test button to call this function separately, and when I call it with `test()`, then the label updates properly.

```
class GoalDetailViewController: UIViewController, TextDelegate {

    @IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject) {
        updateTextView()
    }

    func updateTextView() {
        print(goalSummaryTextBox?.text)
        print("delegate called")
        self.goalSummaryTextBox?.text = GoalsData.summaryText
        print(goalSummaryTextBox?.text)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var goalTitle: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var goalCreationDate: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var goalSummaryTextBox: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        goalSummaryTextBox?.text = GoalsData.summaryText
    }
}
```

`updateTextView()` is being called through a delegate method after I pop a different view controller, as can be seen below:

```
class TextEditViewController: UIViewController {
    var textDelegate: TextDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView?

    func configureView() {
        navigationItem.title = "Edit Description"
        navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem((UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Done, target: self, action: "segue")), animated: true)
    }

    func segue() {
        textDelegate = GoalDetailViewController()

        if let text = textView?.text {    
            GoalsData.summaryText = text
        }

        textDelegate?.updateTextView()        
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: That last sentence might be the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate? I know its calling the function because of the print statements.

Comment: Can you post the code relating to the different view controller that is getting popped off (and triggering the `updateTextView()` call)? It could be that `updateTextView()` is being called on a background queue. Can you also add `print(GoalsData.summaryText)` to `updateTextView()` just to make sure it is indeed different?

Comment: @Mark
`
    func segue() {
        
        textDelegate = GoalDetailViewController()
        
        if let text = textView?.text {
            
            GoalsData.summaryText = text

        }
        
        
        textDelegate?.updateTextView()
        
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        
    }
summaryText does print the correct value. and I tried moving the label update within a dispatch to main queue thing but it didnt affect the outcome

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using implicitly unwrapped optionals with your IBOutlets?

Comment: You could try changing all of your optional unwrapping to a forced unwrapping. That way, if anything is nil, an exception will be thrown. It could be that the textDelegate is nil.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could create a small reproducer app. Then I could debug it locally.

Comment: @Mark  the project can be found here https://github.com/rpcarson/GoalsManager
im not sure what a reproducer app is

Comment: Oh, it's a small app that reproduces the bug. But I can work with the actual app as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line causing the issue is in the `TextEditViewController` below:

```
textDelegate = GoalDetailViewController()
```

What this line does is creates a new instance of `GoalDetailViewController`, and sets it as the delegate to the `TextEditViewController`. But, what you want is the original instance of `GoalDetailViewController` to be the delegate. This is why you were seeing the logs when popping `TextEditViewController`, since it was executing the other instance (which wasn't part of the view hierarchy). It also explains why all your `IBOutlet`s are nil when stepping through `updateTextView()` on the delegate call, and that the button you added updates the text properly.

The solution is to make the delegate connection in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? TextEditViewController {
        destination.textDelegate = self
    }
}
```

Add the above code to your `GoalDetailViewController`.

EDIT:

The below code will ensure that this problem does not happen in the future. Change the delegate's definition to:

```
weak var textDelegate: TextDelegate?
```

and change your protocol to:

```
protocol TextDelegate: class {
    func updateTextView()
}
```

Comment: thank you. on a side note, this is something ive been struggling with: communicating  with a specific instance of the viewcontroller. is prepareForSegue the only way to talk to a specific instance?  and thank you very much this works perfectly

Comment: When using a storyboard, it's one of the easiest ways to link two view controllers together.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please mark it as correct.